# Using SOAP API, how to pass parameters to get Response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap

This is my URL `http://192.168.173.211:138/googleMaps.asmx/CustomerLocationgAddress_Add?`. I am sending parameters like this, but in response I am getting error. The problem is "/" after CustomerLocationgAddress_Add?. How to remove "/"?

http://192.168.173.211:138/googleMaps.asmx/CustomerLocationgAddress_Add?/Zip=2717&First_Name=Sri&Last_Name=Vas&Address1=&Address2=&City=&State=&Zip=&Phone=8125137015&CustomerID=187181&Phone_Type1=&Company_Name=&IsDefault=True

Comment: What error are you getting? Would you show readers your code? Please add these details into your question.

Comment: You are adding the '/' and not showing us how. Either show us your code or stop adding the '/'.